# Web services and partial entity updates

Tags: rest, web-services, soap

We are implementing CRUD interface to manage entities with SOAP messages. What are good practices to allow partial updating of the entity? Meaning the client could update just some attributes of the entity, without having to post the whole entity? Is there more general approach to this than distinct methods for each attribute update?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Patch can be used for partial updates, only sending the fields of the object you want to change. There's an interesting discussion about partial updates [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3206264/application-development/how-to-perform-partial-updates-to-rest-web-api-resources.html).

I'd say it would be more important to make sure the partial update is [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html), i.e. the same update fields in the request result in the same end state of the resource. So if you have internal logic that determines the state of a resource attribute based on the value of another resource attribute that is being updated that might be something to look into. e.g. if the resource as a whole has rules for when parts of it are updated but other parts are not specified (default values for some attributes?), that may cause different outcomes based on the current state of the resource.

If the resource as a whole is just a collection of unrelated attributes then partial updates make sense but if there are dependencies among some attributes and some get updated while others don't, then the end state of the resource has to be idempotent. e.g. does it make sense to update an address but not update the phone number? What happens to the phone number if it's a landline and the address gets updated? Is it set to null? and vice versa. So when doing partial updates it might be worth 'partitioning' the allowed partials based on the domain being updated.